# Parent of QWizardPage changes to QFrame during execution, how to access QWizard?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to store some data in a `QWizard`, then access it from `QWizardPages`. However when I try to access the data from a `QWizardPage` it's parent type changes from `QWizard` to `QForm` during code execution and I can thus no longer access the parent data that way. Why is this so and how can I reliably access data stored in the parent `QWizard` from any of the `QWizardPages`?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QLabel, QVBoxLayout

class WizardExample(QtGui.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WizardExample, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("WizardExample")
        self.setWindowTitle('Wizard example')
        #check data source once and store result
        self._dataExists = False
        self.addPage(Page1(self))

class Page1(QtGui.QWizardPage):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setTitle('Page1')
        self.label = QLabel("Text entry... ")
        self.setObjectName("Page1")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        print("--__init__() parent()._dataExists: "+str(self.parent()._dataExists))
        self.printTypes()

    def printTypes(self):
        print(">>printTypes() self name: "+str(self.objectName())+" self type: "+str(type(self))+" parent name: "+self.parent().objectName()+" parent type: "+str(type(self.parent())))

    def isComplete(self): 
        print(">>isComplete()")
        self.printTypes()
        #fails on the following call
        if self.parent()._dataExists:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        wizard = WizardExample(self)
        wizard.exec_()


if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = None
    if ( not QtGui.QApplication.instance() ):
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    window = AppWindow()
    window.show()
    if ( app ):
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: What happens if you add `self.parent = parent` to `Page1.__init__` and then access `self.parent._dataExists` instead of `self.parent()._dataExists`?

Comment: @figs good idea, that worked, though I still don't understand the root cause.

Comment: I'm not sure either. It may be because assigning `self.parent = parent` keeps a reference to the QWizard object (which might otherwise be being scrapped). You could also compare the difference between `print self.parent()` and `print self.parent` at various points in your code.

Comment: Also you should look into the `setField` and `registerField` methods as they provide a built in way for sharing data between wizard pages and can be easily used for validation of input data. That may be cleaner depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @figs I looked at registerField prior to posting but it requires you to store data in a widget which seems wasteful for what I'm doing. This post helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586848/sharing-variable-between-qwizard-pages-in-pyside-pyqt. Local storage of the parent reference is simple and effective. Thanks.

Comment: `QWizard` uses a `QFrame` internally for the pages. That's why your `.parent()` changes after you add the page to wizard. `QWizardPage` has a `.wizard()` method that would reliably return the wizard if it has one.

Comment: @Avaris Yes, in a page self.wizard() works - but only after the init method has completed, any call to self.wizard from the init returns none. Thanks

Comment: @DonSmythe, It's not about `__init__`. `.wizard()` returns the wizard if page has one and that happens after `.addPage`. Before that page doesn't have a wizard. In your example, `__init__` and `.addPage` are sequential so the difference might not be apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass a reference of the `QWizard` to the `QWizardPage` when creating the page you can just store this reference and use it later (see comment of [figs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752791/pyqt4-qwizard-changes-type-to-qframe-during-execution-and-cant-access-parent-fr#comment43916678_27752791)).

Or you can access the `QWizard` from within the `QWizardPage` with the `wizard()` method (mentioned in the comment of [Avaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752791/pyqt4-qwizard-changes-type-to-qframe-during-execution-and-cant-access-parent-fr#comment43926086_27752791)) which was probably added for exactly that reason (that the parent changes internally).